# MySQL - concatenate and joins

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

have 3 following tables:

1. users (id, name)
2. projects (id, name)
3. user_to_project (user_id, project_id)

Every user can be assigned to more than one project and this is stored in the user_to_project table. I want to get a user name and all the projects he's assigned to in one field separated with commas. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
users.id AS 'ID', 
users.name AS 'Name', 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (projects.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM user_to_project 
INNER JOIN projects ON (projects.id = user_to_project.project_id)
INNER JOIN users ON (users.id = user_to_project.user_id)) AS 'Projects'
FROM users
```

It gets me all assigned projects in every row which is not that I want. How to fix this?

Comment: In order to get one result row per user_id, you'd have to aggregate your records by using `GROUP BY user_id`.

Comment: That's not the only problem, I don't understand how this even works without a relation condition to the outer query, should throw an error `More then one row..` @ThorstenKettner

Comment: @sagi: You are right, this is not the only mistake, but it is what to start with :-) The subquery returns one value only: the conactenation of all projects over all records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery, but you want a correlation clause:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
        FROM user_to_project tup INNER JOIN
             projects p
             ON p.id = utp.project_id 
        WHERE u.id = utp.user_id
       ) as Projects
FROM users u;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases.  They make a query easier to write and to read.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and column names (and your column aliases don't require any escape character).
- This is different from a version using `INNER JOIN`, because this will keep all users, even those with no projects.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any reason for this correlated query, and you were missing a condition inside to relate it to the outer query. You also needed a group by clause.

This query should give you all the projects for each `ID` :

```
SELECT users.id, users.name , 
       GROUP_CONCAT (projects.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM user_to_project 
INNER JOIN projects ON (projects.id = user_to_project.project_id)
INNER JOIN users ON (users.id = user_to_project.user_id) 
GROUP BY users.id,users.name
```

**Note:** To make your query work, all you need is to drop the users table from the inner query, and keep the condition.

Comment: Who is always down voting me for the correct answer?!

Comment: Does that happen more often to you? I, too, was surprised you got a downvote. Makes no sense. (There is a closing parenthesis too many in your query, by the way. And Gordon is right in his answer to point out that the wrong type of quotes is being used on the alias names. But anyway, your answer is good!)

Comment: Yea, I had typos there:S . Yes, not to much, but enough to make me suspicious and angry(second one for today) .. @ThorstenKettner